# How to highlight selected area of map with clicking on its name in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can change background-image of selected area with javascript. When I click on Mazandaran in my table I want to have the area of Mazandaran highlighted.I use map tag.can anybody help me?

html:

```
<table style="float:right;width:500px;height:500px;">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" target="#mazandaran">Mazandaran</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="iran3">
    <img src="img/newmap.png" usemap="#newiran" />
    <img id="overlay" src="" />
</div>
<map name="newiran" id="iran6">
    <area alt="mazandaran" shape="poly" href="#" id="mazandaran" coords="95,63,92,68,96,72,98,75,103,77">
```

css code:

```
#iran3 {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:282px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#iran3 > img:first-child {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
}
#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top:-200px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

javascript code:

```
mazandaran.onmouseover = function () {
    overlay.src = 'img/mazandaran.png';
    overlay.style.left = '90px';
    overlay.style.top = '62px';
}
```

Comment: I swear I don't understand your English. What do you mean with: _I want to when I click on Mazandaran in my table,the area of Mazandaran are heighlighted_

Comment: And better use JQuery. You will save lifes.

Comment: Mazandaran is a region in Iran. He is taking about clicking on the region in Map.

Comment: my English is not good.for example.I have map of continents and I want to when I hover or click on Asia in tag a, background color of area of Asia was changed

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately unless you're prepared to get very involved with jquery and loading plugins, there's not much versatility in basic html and javascript for what you are doing.

You can look into plugins such as mapper.js (www.netzgesta.de/mapper/).